# How to get notified if a user has pressed 'print screen' key while application doesn't have focus?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want an app to get notified if a user has pressed 'print screen' key while window has or doesn't have focus.

Comment: You may be able to do that with a [low level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)). Disclaimer: I've never done exactly what you are asking for here.

Comment: [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-raw-input) allows a thread to get notified on input even when it isn't the foreground thread.

Comment: I am taking a look into these.

Comment: Are you interested in observing keyboard input or do you want to get notified about changes to the clipboard?

Comment: @IInspectable I want to save the screenshot of monitor to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to detect 'print screen' itself, but you can monitor the clipboard for the appearance of Bitmap data.

```
static UINT auPriorityList[] = { CF_BITMAP, CF_TEXT, CF_UNICODETEXT };

if (GetPriorityClipboardFormat(auPriorityList, 3) == CF_BITMAP)
{
   if (OpenClipboard(hWnd))
   {
        hBM = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
        ...
        EmptyClipboard();
        CloseClipboard();
   }
}
```

Comment: Any graphics app can put bitmap data on the clipboard. This approach won't tell you whether the bitmap was generated due to the `Print Screen` key or not.

Comment: What if there are more than one app using image in clipboard? In C# WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD does the trick but in C++ it is not working.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN#creating-a-clipboard-format-listener is how it is to be done.

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? After you refer to the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard?redirectedfrom=MSDN#example-of-a-clipboard-viewer),whether the problem is solved?